# Not able to run the suite while keyword is called in keyword file

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I am trying to read data from excel file and run my test suite
While I have my keyword in *** Keywords *** section in test suite file, it is working fine

While I have my keyword defined in separate keyword file, it is giving me error:

```
[ ERROR ] [ DataDriver ] Error in robot file:
  File "C:\Users\EKEENAV\Documents\Mobily\mobilysanitytestautomation\Test_Suite\Sanity_Case.robot", line 0
[ ERROR ] In source file:
  File "../InputData/Test_Cases.xlsx", line 0
[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: AttributeError: No "Test Template" keyword found for first test case.
```

Test E2E Product Offering Flow

Code:

```
  *** Settings ***
Library    DataDriver    file=../InputData/Test_Cases.xlsx    sheet_name=TestCase
Resource          ../Keywords/test_template.robot
Test Template    E2E Product Offering Flow

*** Keywords ***
E2E Product Offering Flow
    [Arguments]    ${IMSI}    ${AccountID}    ${customerType}    ${productOfferingId}    ${productOfferingId2}    ${Subscription}    ${ForceRenewal}    ${Upgrade}    ${Downgrade}    ${Disconnect}
    Set Test Variable    ${IMSI}
    Set Test Variable    ${AccountID}
    Set Test Variable    ${customerType}
    Set Test Variable    ${productOfferingId}
    Set Test Variable    ${productOfferingId2}
    Run Keyword If    '${Subscription}' == 'YES'    Verify Subscription Order Flow
    Run Keyword If    '${ForceRenewal}' == 'YES'    Verify ForceRenewal Order Flow
    Run Keyword If    '${Upgrade}' == 'YES'    Verify Upgrade Order Flow
    Run Keyword If    '${Downgrade}' == 'YES'    Verify Downgrade Order Flow
    Run Keyword If    '${Disconnect}' == 'YES'    Verify Unsubscribe Order Flow

*** Test Cases ***
Test E2E Product Offering Flow    ${IMSI}   ${AccountID}    ${customerType}    ${productOfferingId}    ${productOfferingId2}    ${Subscription}    ${ForceRenewal}    ${Upgrade}    ${Downgrade}    ${Disconnect}
    E2E Product Offering Flow
    #${IMSI}   ${AccountID}    ${customerType}    ${productOfferingId}    ${productOfferingId2}    ${Subscription}    ${ForceRenewal}    ${Upgrade}    ${Downgrade}    ${Disconnect}
```